# How to make a GameObject show after an animation in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I'm creating a 2D in in Unity and I have a loading screen, that it's working (the loading animation). What I want to do next is to make the next screen appear (it's a gameobject), after a certain time.
Right now, my code is:

```
    public RectTransform mainIcon;
    public float timeStep;
    public float oneStepAngle;


    float startTime;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        startTime = Time.time;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Time.time - startTime >= timeStep) {

            Vector3 iconAngle = mainIcon.localEulerAngles;
            iconAngle.z += oneStepAngle;

            mainIcon.localEulerAngles = iconAngle;

            startTime = Time.time;
        }
    }
```

what should I do now? Thank you

Comment: `if(Time.time >= certain value){ Go to next scene }` ?

Comment: this might be an option, yes!
do you think it will work with a gameobject?

Comment: of course ... I would need to know more about your actual complete desired behavior ... I think using a simple Coroutine for rotating your icon the desired amount of time and then simply go to the next scene when done would probably be easiest ...

Comment: Well, what I want to achieve is:
I created one overlay where the loading wheel appears. After a certain period of time, I want to move forward to the next overlay in the hierarchy

Hopefully, I was clear :)

Comment: so just to confirm: There is no actual loading happening, you just want to add an artificial delay? And is the step wise rotation required or why not simply use `void Update(){ mainIcon.Rotate(Vector3.forward, anglePerSecond * Time.deltaTime); }` .. just trying to narrow down what `after an animation` means to you as actually there doesn't seem to be a fix moment when your animation is done

Comment: so, there is no actual loading happening. I have an image that it's rotating and I want that rotation to stop after a certain period of time, and move to the next panel

Answer (score 0):

go to your game object that plays animation > create new script and ignore on start & update > Add this code

```
// object that would appear after animaton
public GameObject obj;

void showGameObject(){
  objSetActive(true);
}
```

go back to your object that plays animation then add game object that will appear > go to animation controller on same object > select animation that our object will appear after > add animation event > in inspector you should have [this](https://miro.medium.com/max/640/1*U60orgoWrUFo0JJ6QUeZLA.jpeg) > select function showGameObject

Comment: I don't think OP is actually talking about animations ... I think they refer to their code in `Update` as the "animation"

Comment: It's not a real animation, sorry if i said that wrongly
What I want to do is a loading wheel (that moves accordingly with an angle and time) and, after x time, I want it to close the overlay this loading is on, and go to the next one (next element in the hierarchy)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple timer like e.g.

```
public RectTransform mainIcon;
public float anglePerSecond = 90f;
public float duration;
public string nextScene;

private float timer;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    mainIcon.Rotate(Vector3.forward * anglePerSecond * Time.deltaTime);

    timer += Time.deltaTime;

    if(timer >= duration)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(nextScene);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, this looks like it could work! But, instead of loading the next scene, I can just make a certain GameObject become active, such as:
GameObject.Find ("Object_Name");
GameObject.SetActive(true);

Comment: I followed your tip, and tried to use the next game object instead, but it's not working... Don't know what I'm doing wrong